# Create Apache Beam Pipeline that read from Google Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I am trying to create a stream pipeline using apache-beam, that read sentences from google pub/sub and write the words into a Bigquery Table.

I am using `0.6.0` apache-beam version.

Following the examples, I have made this:

```
public class StreamingWordExtract {

/**
 * A DoFn that tokenizes lines of text into individual words.
 */
static class ExtractWords extends DoFn<String, String> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        String[] words = ((String) c.element()).split("[^a-zA-Z']+");
        for (String word : words) {
            if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                c.output(word);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A DoFn that uppercases a word.
 */
static class Uppercase extends DoFn<String, String> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        c.output(c.element().toUpperCase());
    }
}


/**
 * A DoFn that uppercases a word.
 */
static class StringToRowConverter extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        c.output(new TableRow().set("string_field", c.element()));
    }

    static TableSchema getSchema() {
        return new TableSchema().setFields(new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>() {
            // Compose the list of TableFieldSchema from tableSchema.
            {
                add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("string_field").setType("STRING"));
            }
        });
    }

}

private interface StreamingWordExtractOptions extends ExampleBigQueryTableOptions, ExamplePubsubTopicOptions {
    @Description("Input file to inject to Pub/Sub topic")
    @Default.String("gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt")
    String getInputFile();

    void setInputFile(String value);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StreamingWordExtractOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
            .withValidation()
            .as(StreamingWordExtractOptions.class);

    options.setBigQuerySchema(StringToRowConverter.getSchema());

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    String tableSpec = new StringBuilder()
            .append(options.getProject()).append(":")
            .append(options.getBigQueryDataset()).append(".")
            .append(options.getBigQueryTable())
            .toString();

    p.apply(PubsubIO.read().topic(options.getPubsubTopic()))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractWords()))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new StringToRowConverter()))
            .apply(BigQueryIO.Write.to(tableSpec)
                    .withSchema(StringToRowConverter.getSchema())
                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));

    PipelineResult result = p.run();


}
```

I have an error near:

`apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractWords()))`

because the previous `apply` not return a `String` but an `Object`

I suppose that the problem is the type returned from `PubsubIO.read().topic(options.getPubsubTopic())`. The type is `PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<T>>` instead of `PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<String>>`

Which is the correct way to read from google pub/sub using apache-beam?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are hitting a recent backwards-incompatible change in Beam -- sorry about that!

Starting with Apache Beam version 0.5.0, `PubsubIO.Read` and `PubsubIO.Write` need to be instantiated using `PubsubIO.<T>read()` and `PubsubIO.<T>write()` instead of the static factory methods such as `PubsubIO.Read.topic(String)`.

Specifying a coder via `.withCoder(Coder)` for the output type is required for `Read`. Specifying a coder for the input type, or specifying a format function via `.withAttributes(SimpleFunction<T, PubsubMessage>)` is required for `Write`.

Comment: I find it hard to find any documentation on how to write a coder, any guides or documentation?

Comment: Coder API: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/package-summary.html. That said, you might not need to write a Coder -- there's a built-in coder for many types. Finally, you can also read PubSub messages as bytes, and do any required conversion in a ParDo that follows -- this might be (much) simpler.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, actually managed to work around everything by using the StringCoder and working from there.